# Delegate error for UIStepper in TableViewCell and TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uistepper

I have an issue with my delegate for `UIStepper`, `TableViewCell` and `TableViewController`. I am unable to pass a delegate command to my `TableViewCell` in the `TableViewController`.

My `TableViewCell` code is as below:

**CampTableCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol ReviewCellDelegate{
    func stepperButton(stepper_value:Int)
}

class CampTableCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var campqty: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var stepper: UIStepper!

var delegate:ReviewCellDelegate!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {

    self.delegate.stepperButton(Int(stepper.value))
    campqty.text = String(Int(stepper.value))
}

}
```

The start of my **TableGenController.swift** is this:

```
class TableGenController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, ReviewCellDelegate {
```

and I have added this function (as a test):

```
func stepperButton(stepper_value:Int) {
    print("Value Changed!")
}
```

Next, I believe, is I have to add this under viewDidLoad:

```
CampTableCell.delegate = self
```

However, this causes an error stating that:

```
Instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 'CampTableCell'
```

I might be doing something conceptually wrong, but it's been difficult to find resources for this particular setup. Would be really grateful for some help on this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proficient in delegates, but have you tried removing the line with the error? I'm not sure you need it.

Also I think you can remove `self` in

```
self.delegate.stepperButton(Int(stepper.value))
```